# Insert record and re-sequence Primary Key - Access 2013 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm very much an Visual Basic noob... I'm trying to create a button on my Access form that can create a record and re-sequence my non-auto-incremented Primary Key to insert the record where I want it in the record list.

Currently, to do this I 1) Open the table, 2) use an AutoHotKey keyboard macro to manually edit the Primary Key number from the last record to where I want to insert my new record, 3) create a new record (with an appropriate value in my Primary Key column) at the bottom of the list, then 4) Right-click the column and "Sort from smallest to largest", and finally 5) use a second AutoHotKey macro to re-sequence the Primary Key from the new record to the end of the list.

I'd like a Command Button that will allow me to do the same with just one click.

The database currently has 897 records- adding a new record at #185 using the method I currently use seems tedious when it seems a FOR / NEXT (Step -1) Loop in VBA would be so much more efficient.

Some names I use:

- Form Name: [Anime Input Form]
- Table Name: [DVDs and Blu Rays]
- Primary Key Name: [AIN#]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this - where the field is named Priority and you are using the AfterUpdate event of this:

```
Private Sub Priority_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rst             As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngId           As Long
    Dim lngPriorityNew  As Long
    Dim lngPriorityFix  As Long

    ' Save record.
    Me.Dirty = False

    ' Prepare form.
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    Me.Repaint
    Me.Painting = False

    ' Current Id and priority.
    lngId = Me!Id.Value
    lngPriorityFix = Nz(Me!Priority.Value, 0)
    If lngPriorityFix <= 0 Then
        lngPriorityFix = 1
        Me!Priority.Value = lngPriorityFix
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

    ' Rebuild priority list.
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.MoveFirst
    While rst.EOF = False
        If rst!Id.Value <> lngId Then
            lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityNew + 1
            If lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityFix Then
                ' Move this record to next lower priority.
                lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityNew + 1
            End If
            If Nz(rst!Priority.Value, 0) = lngPriorityNew Then
                ' Priority hasn't changed for this record.
            Else
                ' Assign new priority.
                rst.Edit
                    rst!Priority.Value = lngPriorityNew
                rst.Update
            End If
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Reorder form and relocate record.
    Me.Requery
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.FindFirst "Id = " & lngId & ""
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

    ' Present form.
    Me.Painting = True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: _AfterUpdate() rather than _Click()?

Comment: I want a "New Record" button so If I have 897 records and want to insert a record after #205, I'm thinking I need to have it:

1) Create new blank record 898,
2) Increment all records 206-898 to 207-899
3) Change record 899 to 206.

Comment: Actually, I have a "New Record" button- I want an "Insert Record" button.

Comment: No, it is much simpler. No click or button. You just write the new record assigning it 206. It will automatically be sequenced. Later, change any record to, say, 334, and it will automatically be repositioned.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but what you're suggesting makes fundamental changes to how I want my database to function and how I interact with it.

I just want a button the the form that creates a new record after the currently selected record in the form.

Comment: Relax and be a bit creative. Let the button read the current Id, go to a new record, then insert `id + 1`. Done.

Comment: Okay, so I've changed the line to

"lngId = Me!AIN#.Value"

 and I get "Microsoft Access can't find the field 'AIN' referred to in your expression", my cursor is an hourglass I can't get rid of, and text from the 'DVDs and Blu Rays" table under the form window are popping through the Form.

Comment: Don't use weird field or control names. You may have to use `Me![AIN#].Value` or `Me("AIM#").Value` - or just rename `AIM#` to `AIM` throughout.

Comment: "Microsoft Access can't find the field "Priority" referred to in your expression."

Comment: I'm not going to create a new field in my form named "Priority".  I want a BUTTON to CLICK. Not a field to type in.

Comment: Please understand that you may have to modify the function to your actual need. `Priority` was the field in my table - adjust its name to fit yours.

Comment: I understand and appreciate you are trying to help, but really- I asked for "X" and you gave me "Y", and when I say "That isn't X", you tell me to change my question so "Y" is the correct answer.

By the way, if you're re-sorting the records from the current record to the end and using the rst.MoveNext statement, doesn't that create two records with the same Primary Key value, which can't be allowed because the Primary Key must have a unique value for each record?

Comment: Yes, that's why I use the Priority field. Thinking about it, you should not (in fact never) change the Id of a record - it should at all time be meaningless and serve the single purpose of identifying the record. So, as I guess `AIN#` has a meaning for you, use this is the Priority field and add an AutoNumber Id field to your table. Then the sequence would be:  Let the button read the current `AIN#`, go to a new record, then insert this current AIN + 1 in `AIN#` and save the record.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in spite of the protests, I've come up with a solution.  Is it bad practice?  Probably- But my database is mine to fiddle with, and I'll set it up the way I want it.

Maybe at some point, if the collection gets so large that this method becomes inefficient, I can always add a new column, make it auto-increment, and set that as the primary key and go from there.

Until then...

```
Private Sub Command101_Click()

    Dim CurrentRecord As Integer
    Dim LastRecord As Integer
    Dim NewRecord As Integer

'Pause screen and show it's busy
        DoCmd.Hourglass True
        Me.Painting = False

'just create new record at end of list if that's where you are
    If AIN = DMax("AIN", "DVDs and Blu Rays") Then
        CurrentRecord = AIN
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        AIN = CurrentRecord + 1
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    Else
'Save the current record value
        CurrentRecord = AIN

'Create new record at the end of list and give it a new record number
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
        LastRecord = AIN
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        AIN = LastRecord + 1
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

'Increment all records by one working backwards from end to current record
        While AIN <> CurrentRecord
            AIN = AIN + 1
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
        Wend

'Return to last record and insert it after the current record
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
        AIN = CurrentRecord + 1
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

'Unpause screen
        Me.Painting = True
        DoCmd.Hourglass False

'Refresh the form so new record is in correct location and open it
        Me.Requery
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, CurrentRecord + 1
    End If
End Sub
```